# If cell contains (x,y or z) allow for another cell to display its formula value

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have three columns "BF", "SF", and "LF" whose cells have theire own unique formulas.  Currently, regardless of what is entered in column "Species" the BF, SF, and LF cells will compute and display their formula values.

[image: Screenshot]

I need help in trying to assign the formula cells to only display their formula values if the "Species" column matches a certain criteria. . .

Example:

For the BF column I would like it to display it's formulas value ONLY if the "Species" column matches any of the following. . .DF#1 GRN, DF#2 GRN, DF#1 GRN FOHC, Borate, Borate KDAT, ACQ, ACQ KDAT. . .Or possibly there is a way to say that if the cell contains DF or ACQ or Borate

For the SF Column I would like it to display it's formulas value ONLY if the "Species" column matches any of the following. . .OSB, OSB S1, CDX, CDX S1, ACX, CCX

Any help you can provide would be greatly appreciated.  Thank you for your time.

Comment: You could use conditional formatting to only display the values when you want to. If the cells have needed formulas you can still render their contents conditionally invisible by background and font selection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You simply need an IF statement with OR logic inside. The following will display 100 if "DF#1 GRN" or "DF#2 GRN" is present in cell A2. If they are not, it will display nothing (""). You just need to put your formula in place of the 100, and add all the cases you need to the OR() separated by a comma.

```
=IF(OR(A2 = "DF#1 GRN", A2 = "DF#2 GRN"), 100, "")
```

If you want to search for substrings instead of checking if the entire cell is equal to a value, you can use `ISNUMBER` and `SEARCH` as seen below. This will check if either "DF" or "Bo" exists in cell A2 and print either 100 or nothing based on that.

```
=IF(OR(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("DF", A2)), ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Bo", A2))), 100, "")
```

Comment: Thank you Alex for your reply, if I want it to match partial descriptions do you know how I could accomplish that?  Like for example - matching if the cell contains 'DF' or 'Bo' or 'WRC'?

Comment: @BryanM `=ISNUMBER(SEARCH("DF", A2))` will return true or false if the substring "DF" is present in the cell.  You can use this to replace `A2 = "DF#1GRN"` in my answer. For example, `=IF(OR(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("DF", A2)), ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Bo", A2))), 100, "")` will search A2 for the text "DF" and "Bo" and if either exists it will display 100.

Comment: I updated the answer with the info from the previous comment.

Answer (score 0):

So, you want another `IF` statement with a check for something like `LEN(A1)<>LEN(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"DF",""),"ACQ",""),"Borate",""))`?

Comment: is that a "greater than/less than" symbol you have in the formula. . .< >?

Comment: Can you show me what would be an example for the BF column cell C5 and corresponding A5?  Thank you for your help Chronocidal

Comment: All it does is take the value in cell A1, replaces "DF", "ACQ" and "Borate" with nothing, then checks if the Length has changed (Old Length not equal to New Length)